# nuked my centos path settings

Tags: unix, centos, centos5, root

i, by mistake, nuked my centos path settings by adding a wrong path. i added the following :

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0/bin
export PATH
```

to /etc/profile/bashrc and now all the commands are gone.

could someone please help me restore my system.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

One way of setting your path without breaking it is:

`export PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0/bin:$PATH`

A short explanation. When you want to add something new to your path, you should keep the old path settings. What you did was to set the path to point only to /usr/local/jdk1.6.0/bin. That's why all the other commands except from the ones found in /usr/local/jdk1.6.0/bin are "gone". Nothing is really "gone". You just need to reset your path. Just open a new shell/terminal instance or simply logout/login and set your path using a more proper way.

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Comment: @Smadey [Provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!